# App icon badge visible by default

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework

I am having a hard time to make this work. What Im using:

```
1 - The Ionic Framework (version 1.7.14)
2 - Ionic push which is instantiated with: Ionic.Push. So Im not using ngcordova for push
3  -A real device, an Iphone 6s. And I am on OSX.
```

Since I began sending push notifications from Ionic Push

```
http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-overview
```

something strange happened. I have sent a certain number of pushes both from curl and my own backend application.

The problem was that that badge with number "1" never disappeared from the app icon. I have tried to delete and reinstall the app using Iphone and xcode. But each time the app is installed, the badge with the number 1 is directly shown on the app icon. And even when I go inside the app and then close it, then the badge is still there. Why?

I didnt really understand who should take care of resetting the badge on the app icon. Is it the javascript code in Ionic?
SHouldn't it be managed by default by the OS? Shouldn't the OS clear the badge on the app icon as soon as you open the app that has badges?
I had this code in my js-controller:

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
    "debug": true,
    "pluginConfig": {
        "ios": {
            "badge": false,
            "sound": true
        },
        "android": {
            "iconColor": "#343434"
        }
    }
});
```

However, it didnt help. The badge on the app icon is still there.

So as a last thing I did the following:

```
1 - I removed the code for push in javascript.
2 - I opened "settings" on my iphone and disabled my app to be updated in background.
```

No luck. The damned badge is still there in the right top corner of my app icon.

Comment: The badges don't disappear on their own - you have to use something like the [`badge`](http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge) cordova API to clear the badge status.

Comment: You need to write `cordova` code for resetting the Badge. And `"badge": false,` you need to use `"badge": 0`, this will also remove the badge count.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

Change **"badge" : false** to **"badge" : 0**

Because badge denotes the total count of notification and not boolean Value for show/hide.

Give it as **0**

Hope it helps..

Comment: According to [Phonegap Push Plugin documentation](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushnotificationinitoptions) "badge" is indeed a boolean.

Comment: I suggested for iPhone push notification. In iOS, badge meant for the total count of notifications.

Comment: Opener asked help on configuring pluginConfig options correctly. The json used to send an actual notification by means of Ionic platform is OT here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ionic documentation](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-usage#section-plugin-options) on push, options specified in pluginConfig are passed to [Phonegap Push Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushnotificationinitoptions).

If you look at the plugin documentation you'll see that clearBadge option is what you are looking for, this should be specified both for android and ios, like this:

```
"pluginConfig": {
  "ios": {
    "badge": true,
    "sound": true,
    "clearBadge": true
  },
  "android": {
    "clearBadge": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Phonegap plugin push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push), you can also do this.

```
var pushNotification = PushNotification.init(
          { "android": {"senderID": config.senderId, "icon": "notification","clearBadge":"true"},
            "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "false", "sound": "true", "clearBadge": "true"},
            "windows": {} } );

pushNotification.on('notification', function(data) {
            pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function() {
                    console.log("clear badge success");
                }, function() {
                    console.log("clear badge error");
                }, 0);  //setting 0 will clear the badge

            console.log("notification " + JSON.stringify(data));

        });
```

You can see the [doc](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushsetapplicationiconbadgenumbersuccesshandler-errorhandler-count---ios--android-only) here